# Laravel eloquent two has many relation

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I've tried it too many times but I still can't get it.
I am trying to make a custom tour app with laravel. I have 3 models which is **User - Request - Offer**
User has many requests, request has many offers
but the offer and request both belong to user, it is because of the user table have two roles, one as a traveler and one as a travel agents.

here is my model
**class user**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'contact_number',
    'photo',
    'birthday',
    'about',
    'email',
    'agency',
    'logo',
    'role',
    'status_agency',
    'is_admin',
    'legal',
    'password',
];
public function custom_tour_requests()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\custom_tour_request', 'traveler_id');        
}
public function custom_tour_offers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\custom_tour_offer', 'App\custom_tour_request');       
}
```

**class custom_tour_request**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title' ,
    'departure' ,
    'destination' ,
    'description' ,
    'start_date' ,
    'end_date',
    'budget' ,
    'adult' ,
    'child' ,   
    'traveler_id'       
];
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\user');
}
public function custom_tour_offers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\custom_tour_offer', 'custom_tour_request_id');       
}
```

**class custom_tour_offer**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'departure',
    'destination',
    'itinerary',
    'include',
    'exclude',
    'start_date',
    'end_date',
    'price'
];
public function custom_tour_request()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\custom_tour_request');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\user');
}
```

Whenever I tried to insert it return error,

```
$travelagent = user::find(Auth::user()->id);        
$customtourRequest =   $travelagent->custom_tour_offers()->create($requests->all());
```

I can't change my database design. I am so confused.

Comment: You should provide the error you are getting.

Comment: @HakanAktaş it said constrain fail, it need the custom tour request id..i try to use a query builder to insert it manually and it works. but not with eloquent
the problem is i need the travler id for offer and also the request id from the request

Answer (score 0):

whats the error?
have you re-check the docs and the api for that?
maybe you forgot the first() before the create method.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasManyThrough.html

i personally like to do it like

   `custom_tour_offer::create($request->all());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and post the results:

```
$tourOffers = $travelagent->custom_tour_offers();
$queryBuilder = $tourOffers->getQuery();
$sql = $queryBuilder->getGrammar()->compileInsert($queryBuilder, $requests->all());

dd($sql);
```